# Passing webdriver object from one sample to another

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

In JMeter, I have the code below in a JSR223 Sampler with groovy scripting language selected.

I would like to measure the time taken for different custom defined user actions in a flow at the GUI level. I am thinking of doing this by splitting the code below across different JSR223 Samplers and then reading the time each sample took to execute.

I just don't know how to pass the initial WebDriver object instance from one sampler to another so that I can continue some actions on the same browser and user flow.

I'd greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.Duration
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

    // webdrivermanager-5.3.3-fat.jar is in jmeter lib folder
    io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true)
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
    def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5))

    //1 sample start
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//button/div[contains(string(), 'Accept all')]")))
    //1 sample end

    //2 sample start
    ACCEPTALL_BUTTON = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button/div[contains(string(), 'Accept all')]"))
    ACCEPTALL_BUTTON.click()
    SEARCH_TEXTBOX = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@title ='Search']"))
    SEARCH_TEXTBOX.sendKeys("test")
    SEARCH_BUTTON = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div[4]/center//input[@value ='Google Search']"))
    //2 sample end

    //3 sample start
    SEARCH_BUTTON.click()
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("result-stats")))
    //3 sample end

    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `driver.quit()` put the instance of WebDriver into [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) like:

```
vars.putObject('driver', driver)
```

then in another JSR223 Sampler you will be able to get it back:

```
def driver = vars.getObject('driver')
```

More information:

- [JMeterVariables.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object))
- [JMeterVariables.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String))
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

You might also take a look at [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which instantiates a WebDriver at the Thread Group start and shuts it down then the virtual user execution finishes. It's also suitable for executing > 1 thread.